# Rails_admin partial not recognizing variables passed through argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin, local-variables, partials

I want to be able to do something like this

```
rails_admin do
  partial "custom_view", variable: my_variable
end
```

Rails_admin does not complain, but the model variable is not recognizable inside the partial neither

I tried few other syntaxes such as : `partial "custom_view", :variable => my_variable` or `partial "custom_view", :locales { :variable => my_variable }`but no luck...

Any clues how to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Today had the same question. I poked around using documentation here https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL

```
  config.model YourModel do
    edit do
      field :field_name do
        def render
          bindings[:view].render :partial => 'rails_admin/main/name_of_partial', :locals => {:field => self, :form => bindings[:form], variable: my_variable}
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

And put your partial under views/rails_admin/main/name_of_partial.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the previous comments, I manage to use a partial with this kind of code:

```
show do
  configure :candidacy do
    pretty_value do
      bindings[:view].render({
         partial: "rails_admin/custom_partials/project_candidacy",
         locals: {candidacy: value}
      ).html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

The important is to not forget the **.html_safe** after you render your partial

Answer (score 0):

Try `render partial: "custom_view", locals: { variable: my_variable }`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really give enough information, but the answer above is close. For one variable, you can do something like

```
render partial: "foo/custom_view", admin: @user
```

or

```
render partial: "foo/custom_view", locals: { admin: @user }
render partial: "foo/custom_view", object: @user, as: 'admin'
```

unless it is a collection, then you would

```
render partial: "foo/custom_view", things: @things
```

or

```
render partial: "foo/custom_view", locals: { things: @things }
render partial: "foo/custom_view", collection: @things, as: 'things'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but non of them works ! The variable inside the partial is not being recognized when i try to print it in the view as first line on the page...

Comment: do you have the code posted anywhere? if you do, i can take a look.